# How to check if connection pool is used

Tags: java, database, jdbc, hsqldb

I use HSQLDB + EclipseLink + Gemini on OSGI framework (Felix). In spite that I've set pool in persistence.xml I have serious suspicious that connection pool is not used and for every request a new connection is created. How can I check on HSQLDB side if conection pool is used.

**EDIT 1**
I start my application with `-Dhsqldb.reconfig_logging=false`. To start HSQLDB server in my application I use the following code

```
p.setProperty("server.database.0", "file:"+dataBasePath);
p.setProperty("server.dbname.0", "testdb");
p.setProperty("server.port", "9001");
server = new Server();
```

And this is my jdbc url:

```
 jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/testdb;hsqldb.write_delay=false;hsqldb.sqllog=3;hsqldb.applog=3;server.silent=false
```

However, in my logs I still don't get any messages about using connection pool. This is my log:

```
2017-04-14 11:01:57,373 | INFO  | Server @48b135ed | org.hsqldb.lib.FrameworkLogger | open start - state modified
2017-04-14 11:01:57,396 | INFO  | Server @48b135ed | org.hsqldb.lib.FrameworkLogger | dataFileCache open start
2017-04-14 11:01:57,407 | INFO  | Server @48b135ed | org.hsqldb.lib.FrameworkLogger | dataFileCache open end
2017-04-14 11:01:57,698 | INFO  | Server @48b135ed | org.hsqldb.lib.FrameworkLogger | checkpointClose start
2017-04-14 11:01:57,699 | INFO  | Server @48b135ed | org.hsqldb.lib.FrameworkLogger | checkpointClose synched
2017-04-14 11:01:57,825 | INFO  | Server @48b135ed | org.hsqldb.lib.FrameworkLogger | checkpointClose script done
2017-04-14 11:01:57,826 | INFO  | Server @48b135ed | org.hsqldb.lib.FrameworkLogger | dataFileCache commit start
2017-04-14 11:01:57,859 | TRACE | Server @48b135ed | org.hsqldb.lib.FrameworkLogger | file sync end
2017-04-14 11:01:57,859 | INFO  | Server @48b135ed | org.hsqldb.lib.FrameworkLogger | dataFileCache commit end
2017-04-14 11:01:57,934 | INFO  | Server @48b135ed | org.hsqldb.lib.FrameworkLogger | checkpointClose end
```

**EDIT 2**
I started Hsqldb in separate process (java -jar ..) and as command line parameter I added `--silent false`. Now on console on this separate process I see the following:

```
[Server@a09ee92]: [Thread[HSQLDB Server @a09ee92,5,main]]: handleConnection(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=38959,localport=9001]) entered
[Server@a09ee92]: [Thread[HSQLDB Server @a09ee92,5,main]]: handleConnection() exited
[Server@a09ee92]: 3:SQLCLI:MODE:31
[Server@a09ee92]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @2b14b766,5,HSQLDB Connections @a09ee92]]: 3:Trying to connect user 'SA' to DB (mydb)
[Server@a09ee92]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @2b14b766,5,HSQLDB Connections @a09ee92]]: 3:Connected user 'SA'
[Server@a09ee92]: 3:SQLCLI:SQLPREPARE SELECT * FROM foo
[Server@a09ee92]: 3:SQLCLI:SQLEXECUTE:1
[Server@a09ee92]: 3:SQLCLI:SQLDISCONNECT
[Server@a09ee92]: [Thread[HSQLDB Server @a09ee92,5,main]]: handleConnection(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=38960,localport=9001]) entered
[Server@a09ee92]: [Thread[HSQLDB Server @a09ee92,5,main]]: handleConnection() exited
[Server@a09ee92]: 4:SQLCLI:MODE:31
[Server@a09ee92]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @f5cabc4,5,HSQLDB Connections @a09ee92]]: 4:Trying to connect user 'SA' to DB (mydb)
[Server@a09ee92]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @f5cabc4,5,HSQLDB Connections @a09ee92]]: 4:Connected user 'SA'
[Server@a09ee92]: 4:SQLCLI:SQLPREPARE SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?))
[Server@a09ee92]: 4:SQLCLI:SQLEXECUTE:1
[Server@a09ee92]: 4:SQLCLI:MODE:18
[Server@a09ee92]: 4:SQLCLI:SQLDISCONNECT
```

This line `HSQLDB Connection @XXXXXXXX` differs for every query and besides for every query I see `Trying to connect user 'SA' to DB (mydb)`. Does it all mean that connection pool is not used?

Comment: I don't know a lot about administration of HSQLDB specifically, but can't you check the log to see when new connections are being created?  Worst case, glancing at the docs:  "*A Server or WebServer instance can be started with the property server.silent=false. This causes all the connections and their executed statements to be printed to stdout as the statements are submitted to the server.*"

Comment: Run as server and follow the advice above  `server.silent=false`. It's the easiest option.

Comment: @fredt Please, see my Edit 1

Comment: Your config is not correct. You need `p.setProperty("server.silent=false");` You should also add the list of the other properties to the path, like `p.setProperty("server.database.0", "file:"+dataBasePath+";hsqldb.write_delay=false;hsqldb.sqllog=3");` and omit the hsqldb.applog=3 as unnecessary. Look at the server output on the console as well.

Comment: @fredt Thank you for your answer. I did as you said. However, result is the same. It seems to me that I don't get any DEBUG messages. Could you say what else could be done?

Comment: Forget your logs. The Server prints the debug messages to stdout. Run the server as a separate process and don't configure logging etc. You can also check the file named xxx.sql.log to see how new sessions are created.

Comment: @fredt Thank you very much for your help. Finally I got server messages. Could you take a look at Edit 2 to help to understand these messages?

Comment: It is obvious that it creates a connection, executes a single SQL statement, and closes the connection.

Comment: @fredt Do I understand you right - connection pool is NOT used?

Comment: We don't know if the connection pool is doing it, or no connection pool is used. Ask a different question with your config etc.

Comment: @fredt I can't find what to say. The point of this question was very clear from the very beginning. Now, when all steps are behind you say - ok, there was no any meaning in doing those steps.

Comment: The answer is: your suspicion turns out to be correct that for every request a new connection is made. The rest can be found only by looking at your settings, as HSQLDB does not know which software made the connection.

Comment: continued: We now know that either the pool is not used at all, or it is not working properly and does not reuse its connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Server messages show that a connection is made, a single SQL statement is executed, and the connection is closed.

Your suspicion turns out to be correct that for every request a new connection is made.

We now know that either the pool is not used at all, or it is not working properly and does not reuse its connections. That is, we don't know if the connection pool is reponsible, or no connection pool is used by the application. This can be found only by looking at your settings, as HSQLDB does not know which software made the connection.