# Find the position of row and total rows with certain where and order by clauses

Tags: sql, database, h2, hsqldb

I have a sql query with `where` and `order by` clauses:

```
SELECT "id" FROM "persons" 
WHERE "id" in (10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100) 
ORDER BY "id" DESC
```

Now I need to get the position of row with id=20 and total amount of found rows in above query. So I do

```
SELECT "id",pos FROM(
   SELECT "id", rownum() as pos FROM(
       SELECT "id" FROM "persons" 
       WHERE "id" in (10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
       ORDER BY "id" DESC
   )
)
WHERE "id"=20;
```

However, my last query only gives me the position of row. How can I now get and total amount of rows? Condition: without `window functions` as I use RDBMS which don't support them - h2 and hsqldb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one with HSQLDB

```
WITH p("id", "pos") AS ( SELECT "id", rownum() AS "pos" FROM "persons" 
   WHERE "id" IN (10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
   ORDER BY "id" DESC) 
SELECT "id", "pos", (select count(*) from P) AS "count" FROM P
WHERE "id"=20;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I needed. If you have a free minute, could you take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43207830/hsqldb-how-to-check-if-connection-pool-is-used ?

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps.

```
 SELECT id,
  (SELECT Count(*) from persons per1 where per1.id< per2.id) AS Rownumber  
 FROM persons per2
 WHERE id in (10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100) 
 ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: No, the result is quite wrong. I get no position no total amount.